# How can I change the name of my game in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have just released my first app game called 'paperplane', now the problem is that there are hunderds of paperplane apps so I dediced the change the name to 'neonplane'. I was not able to change the package name, however i could change the title name which is what I did. I updated the game and waited for google to publish it.

Now it is published it is called neonplane, but here is my problem:

If I look for neonplane I can't find nothing. 
If I look for paperplane I find somewhere down the list neonplane with the name neonplane.

Is it somehow possible to fix this.

Comment: Are you wyve.Inc? If so then your game shows up just fine when I search for *neonplane*.

Comment: Well that is fixed now. But the core game is still called paperplane.

Comment: What do you mean by *core game*?

Comment: The package name is still called paperplane and apperently you cannot change that. So if i would for example share it on facebook. It will still be called paperplane